# Object's life cycle in a WS call

Tags: java, web-services, serialization, soap, marshalling

What happens to a Java object's life when it is passed to a SOAP web service and returned after modification? I know it is serialized, mar-shelled, converted to XML etc. But i am not sure about the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually start with a generated object whose class is decorated with XML annotations.  After filling your object with data, you pass it as a parameter to a web service method.  The JAX-WS libraries will use JAXB and the annotations on your object to marshal it into XML, pack it into a SOAP message, and send it over the network to a web service endpoint.

On the server side, the SOAP message is disassembled and the object XML is unmarshaled.  At this point, the method logic executes and provides a return value.  If that return value is another XML serializable object, we go through the whole process again to marshal and send the response.

Comment: Thanks. How about serialization? Where does that fit?

Comment: Marshaling the object in and out of XML is the serialization portion of the flow.